# Isolating CSS Code

Tags: html, css, animation

I am using a consumer web building program (EverWeb) that has the capability to add HTML snippets to a page. I want to place an additional snippet to a working page, but my code of this last snippet is affecting other snippets on the page.

Is there a way to configure the code so that it stays 'isolated' from other things happening on the page (I am not a coder).

The code I am using is below.

Thanks.

---

```
<img class="big" src="{!-ASSETSPATH-!}Images/big@2x.png" height="65" width="600" alt="" />

<style type="text/css">

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn{ 
0% {opacity: 0;}
38% {opacity: 1;} 
76% {opacity: 1;}
100% {opacity: ;} 
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn{ 
0% {opacity: 0;}
38% {opacity: 1;} 
76% {opacity: 1;}
100% {opacity: ;} 
}
@-o-keyframes fadeIn{ 
0% {opacity: 0;}
38% {opacity: 1;} 
76% {opacity: 1;}
100% {opacity: ;} 
}
@keyframes fadeIn{ 
0% {opacity: 0;}
38% {opacity: 1;} 
76% {opacity: 1;}
100% {opacity: ;} 
}

.big {
opacity:0;
-webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1; 
-moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
-o-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
-moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
-o-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
animation-fill-mode:forwards;

-webkit-animation-duration:8s;
-moz-animation-duration:8s;
-o-animation-duration:8s;
animation-duration:8s;

-webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
-moz-animation-delay: 0s;
-o-animation-delay: 0s;
animation-delay: 0s;
}

</style>
```

Comment: In what way it is "affecting other snippets" on the page?

Comment: I have other snippets that fade in and are coded to stay in their "forward" position. When I place this snippet on the page the others take on the same parameters fading both in and out at the same time as this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution: Use of the same name. I was using the animation name "fadeIn". I changed all instances of this to "imgFade" and all is working.